# TextBox Date doesn't display the Weekday name when I select Sunday from a date box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form in access when has two textboxes. 
The first called txtDateBox which allows the user to select a date.
The second which is called DayBox which displays the days name. 
I have a control source in DayBox to get the name of the day.

```
=WeekdayName(Weekday([txtDateBox])-1)
```

This works fine until I select a sunday date. 
It will then display a #Func! message in the textbox and will not allow me to compile my automatic reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `WeekdayName(0)` triggers error #5, *"Invalid procedure call or argument."*

Avoid the error by using `DateAdd` to subtract one day from `txtDateBox` *before* you give it to `Weekday`.  Here is an Immediate window session to show you what I mean:

```vb
txtDateBox = #2014-1-5#
? Format(txtDateBox, "ddd, mmm d, yyyy")
Sun, Jan 5, 2014
? DateAdd("d", -1, txtDateBox)
1/4/2014 
? Weekday(DateAdd("d", -1, txtDateBox))
 7 
? WeekdayName(Weekday(DateAdd("d", -1, txtDateBox)))
Saturday
```